# Can I minimize a window into a box on Unity?

Tags: unity, window-manager, xdotool, wmctrl

On Irix's  4Dwm, there was an ability to minimise windows into a box (contrary to the task bar used by modern window managers). I have seen this also on an old HPUX.

See the "console" square in the linked image:

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish on Ubuntu, either with a plugin or maybe some  window manager other than Unity?

Comment: Weird, but interesting question :) I could think of something like this. Would the icon matter, or could it be a generic one? How does it behave? like an icon on the desktop or a minimal "window".

Comment: @JacobVlijm The icon is not generic. Each application has it's own icon as the icons of minimised windows in Unity)

Comment: Could be done within Unity as well, but the window would be iconized on the desktop (with the corresponding application's icon and the window's name). Would you fancy a shot? (would be an interesting, but challenging job,  better ask before I start :) )

Comment: Yes this can be helpful to me. I have to work with a lot of open windows and this way of organising them is better in my opinion.  I know nothings about Unity, so I can help only with the testing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To my own surprise, it works quite nicely, *As long as you do not have too many other things on your desktop*.

I worked with it for a while, and it seems a weird, but strangely enough *nice* alternative to frequent workspace switches. Refreshing for its simplicity.

#### In practice

The solution is actually pretty much what you describe:

- Pressing a key combination will "box" the window on your desktop, from a window:

  [image]

  into an icon, with the application's appearance:

  [image]
- Double click the icon, and the window will re- appear and the icon will vanish.

#### How it works

The short story (explanation):

- When pressing the shortcut key, the script is called with the argument `box`:

  ```
  windowbox box
  ```
- The script then:

  - reads the window id of the frontmost window
  - checks if it is a "normal" window (you wouldn't want to unmap your desktop for example)
  - Looks up the process name of the application, owning the window.
  - Looks up the corresponding icon in the corresponding application's `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`
  - creates a uniquely named `.desktop` file, with an `Exec=` line which calls the script (when double-clicked) with the argument `show`:

    ```
    windowbox show
    ```

The `.desktop` file will add a number of additional arguments arguments, such as the window id, the (file-) name of the `.desktop` file.

Subsequently:

- The `.desktop` file is then made executable, to make it a double- clickable object.
- When the `.desktop` file is double clicked, the window is (re-) mapped, the `.desktop` file is removed from your desktop.

#### How to set up

1. Like practically always, when you want to play around with windows, the script needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
   ```
2. Create the directory `~/bin` (`~` stands for your home directory)
3. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `windowbox` (no extension) in `~/bin`.

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import sys
   import os

   # --- On Unity, there is a (y-wise) deviation in window placement
   # set to zero for other window managers
   deviation = 28
   # ---

   args = sys.argv[1:]

   get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

   def find_dtop():
       # get the localized path to the Desktop folder
       home = os.environ["HOME"]
       dr_file = home+"/.config/user-dirs.dirs"
       return [home+"/"+ l.split("/")[-1].strip() \
               for l in open(dr_file).readlines() \
               if l.startswith("XDG_DESKTOP_DIR=")][0].replace('"', "")

   def check_windowtype(w_id):
       # check the type of window; only unmap "NORMAL" windows
       return "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in get(["xprop", "-id", w_id])

   def get_process(w_id):
       # get the name of the process, owning the window and window x/y position
       w_list = get(["wmctrl", "-lpG"]).splitlines()
       pid = [l for l in w_list if w_id in l][0].split()
       proc = get(["ps", "-p", pid[2], "-o", "comm="])
       xy = (" ").join(pid[3:5])
       return (proc, xy)

   def read_f(f, string, proc):
       # search for a possible match in a targeted .desktop file
       try:
           with open(f) as read:
               for l in read:
                   if all([l.startswith(string), proc in l]):
                       in_f = True
                       break
                   else:
                       in_f = False
       except:
           in_f = False
       return in_f

   def get_icon(proc, w_name):
       # search appropriate icon in /usr/share/applications
       exceptions = [item for item in [
           ["soffice", "libreoffice-main"],
           ["gnome-terminal", "utilities-terminal"],
           ["nautilus", "folder"],
           ] if item[0] in proc]
       if exceptions:
           if exceptions == [["soffice", "libreoffice-main"]]:
               loffice = [
                   ["Calc", "libreoffice-calc"],
                   ["Writer", "libreoffice-writer"],
                   ["Base", "libreoffice-base"],
                   ["Draw", "libreoffice-draw"],
                   ["Impress", "libreoffice-impress"],
                   ]
               match = [m[1] for m in loffice if m[0] in w_name]
               if match:
                   return match[0]
               else:
                   return exceptions[0][1]
           else:      
               return exceptions[0][1]
       else:
           default = "/usr/share/applications"
           dtfiles = [default+"/"+f for f in os.listdir(default)]
           for f in dtfiles:
               if read_f(f, "Exec=", proc) == True:   
                   for l in open(f).readlines():
                       if l.startswith("Icon="):
                           icon = l.replace("Icon=", "").strip()
                           print(f)
                           break
                   break
           return icon

   def create_name():
       # create unique (file-) name for boxed window
       n = 1
       while True:
           name = dtop+"/"+"boxed_"+str(n)+".desktop"
           if os.path.exists(name):
               n += 1
           else:
               break
       return name

   def convert_wid(w_id):
       # convert window- id, xdotool format, into wmctrl format
       w_id = hex(int(w_id))
       return w_id[:2]+(10-len(w_id))*"0"+w_id[2:]

   def create_icon(w_id, w_name, icon, pos):
       # create the launcher, representing the boxed window
       boxedwindow = create_name()
       f_content =[
               "[Desktop Entry]",
               "Name=[WINDOW] "+w_name,
               "Exec=windowbox show "+w_id+" '"+boxedwindow+"' "+pos,
               "Icon="+icon,
               "Type=Application",
               ]
       if icon == "generic":
           f_content.pop(3)
       with open(boxedwindow, "wt") as boxed:
           for l in f_content:
               boxed.write(l+"\n")
       command = "chmod +x "+"'"+boxedwindow+"'"
       subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

   if args[0] == "box":
       dtop = find_dtop()
       w_id = convert_wid(get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"]))
       w_name = get(["xdotool", "getwindowname", w_id])
       if check_windowtype(w_id) == True:
           procdata = get_process(w_id)
           procname = procdata[0]
           icon = get_icon(procname, w_name); icon = icon if icon != None else "generic"
           create_icon(w_id, w_name, icon, procdata[1])
           subprocess.call(["xdotool", "windowunmap", w_id])

   elif args[0] == "show":
       w_id = args[1]
       subprocess.call(["xdotool", "windowmap", w_id])    
       subprocess.call(["xdotool", "windowmove", "--sync", w_id, args[3], str(int(args[4])-deviation)])
       os.remove(args[2])
   ```
4. **Make the script executable**
5. To make the newly created directory "pop up" in `$PATH`, either log out/in, or run `source ~/.profile` (from a terminal window)
6. Test- run the script from a terminal window by the command:

   ```
   windowbox box
   ```

   The window should disappear, the "boxed" window should appear on your desktop.
7. If all works fine, add the following command to a shortcut key: choose the gear icon on the top right of your screen:

   [image: Gear icon]
8. Go to <kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> → <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> → <kbd>Custom Shortcuts</kbd>. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> and add the command:

   ```
   windowbox box
   ```

That should do it.

#### Important note

The script uses `xdotool`'s `windowunmap` to make the window invisible. The created "box" (icon) on your desktop is the only "gate" to the hidden window. In other words: don't remove the desktop file(s) manually. The window will be lost for good if you do.

#### Work to do [edit 20-12: *done*]

The script still could use some refinement:

- The window geometry is not restored by definition. Can be fixed very well, but I thought I'd show you the first result.
- In most cases, the boxed window has its correct icon. The function `get_process(w_id)` could use some improvement however. If the process is not found as a command in `/usr/share/applications`, the file has a generic icon.

#### Giving the boxed-window icons a different size than the other icons

The script names the created `.desktop` files *always* `boxed_1.desktop`, `boxed_2.desktop` etc, depending on the "available" name at the moment of creation (filenames, not the displayed name).

You can resize the files (in general), by right- click > icon size. The good news is that if you remove the file and recreate it, the size is remembered. Even if you create the file again after a restart. That means that if you *ever* resized the boxed windows (e.g.) 1-5, they will *always* have the same size when you (the script) create them again!

[image]

Comment: I can't resist myself without leaving a comment, very nice answer from you :)

Comment: Nice! Few comments: 1. I replaced the line `dtop = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad"` with a path to my desktop (`dtop = "/home/" + user + "/Desktop"`) 2. Restoring by double clicking did not work. I suspect that `source ~/.profile` is not enough will log-in/out promptly to test test this. 3. In unity it is possible to resize icons manually (right click -> resize icon), is it possible to add some parameter in `f_content` to set icon's size?

Comment: @Artium   aaaarrrrggggh, my blind spot(s), 1. while working, I thought I should not forget the path to your Desktop, but I did...  2. you can find out by running from a terminal. 3. nice suggestion, I am not sure if you can resize  a *single*  icon.

Comment: It seems that `source ~/.profile` affects PATH only in the terminal where It was executed.

Comment: @Artium That surprises me! I should change a lot of my answers then :) I will edit in the window- geometry probably before the end of the weekend (+ some more minor improvements)

Comment: @Artium thanks for the really nice question by the way. Really great fun to get it working!

Comment: Jacob, after logging out and logging in again, the PATH variable appears correctly and the shortcut for minimising works flawlessly. Thank you for the effort you have put into writing this excellent answer!

Comment: When I started to read the first paragraph of this answer, I just *knew* there would be an orange icon at the bottom!  **;-)  :P**

Comment: @Fabby I tried to change color, really, bu I always come back to orange. :)

Comment: Hi @Artium I updated the script, it has a few important improvements now, including better icon- finding and geometry- restoring, Have fun!

Comment: @The geometry and icon finding works fine. The nautilus icon on my system looks strange so I used folder icon instead. `["nautilus", "folder"]`

Comment: http://imgur.com/mJi6Blj On the left is an icon who's name is "system-file-manager" on the right is an icon named "folder".

Comment: @Artium Haha, that's a funny one indeed, updated the script.

Comment: Small correction, this is "system-file-manager": http://imgur.com/VIkECzS . The funny icon is named "nautilus".

Comment: @Artium I know, but try the one in the script, it is the usual folder icon, similar to your image. probably just a link to the same icon.

Answer (score 7):

You can use **fvwm** to accomplish this.

1. Install fvwm:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install fvwm
   ```
2. Find a them that uses the iconify function - there are several here: http://www.jmcunx.com/fvwm_theme.html Several look like the screen-shot you show.
3. Copy the text of the theme, then navigate to `~/.fvwm/` (show hidden files first) then create a file `.fvwm2rc`
4. Open that file in  a text editor (like gedit) and paste the theme text into it.
5. Reboot the computer, and select fvwm and login.

[image]