# How can I make Nautilus file manager remember my open tabs?

Tags: nautilus

Is it possible to preserve my open tabs between closing and opening of Nautilus file manager?

Preferably even across different logouts and restarts.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52112/remember-what-directories-are-open-in-one-session-of-nautilus

Comment: In one session, or after restart / logout?

Comment: @JacobVlijm preferably even persistent across restart / logout.

Comment: Unless Parto's link provides a solution, nautilus' command line options / integration is quite limited. There is no option to read the currently opened directory, nor to change it from the command line. Remembering what you cannot see seems impossible to me. Within one session a trick & cheat option would be possible though.

Comment: @JacobVlijm mind explaining how to achieve the remembering within one session? That would be already a great thing to begin with. :)

Comment: Since nautilus does not have an "open with" option, we can very well use the trick to *unmap* the window (`xdotool`) instead of actually closing it. The launcher's on-click behaviour would then become: click to open a window, click again to `unmap` (seemingly close) the frontmost nautilus window, click again to show the unmapped window (if an unmapped nautilus window exists) or open a new one if not. A bit like this trick: http://askubuntu.com/a/711198/72216, but without the desktop icon and controlled by the launcher.  That would mean however you control the window(s) by the launcher icon.

Comment: P.S. unmapped windows are *completely* vanished; from the launcher, from the desktop, even from `wmctrl`.

Comment: Posted my answer. curious to what you think.

Comment: Since this is a potentially useful feature to be implemented into Nautilus directly, I created [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762721) bug report. Please feel free to react there, too.

Comment: A tabbed file manager with **opened tab persistence over boots** is essential for my productivity. It is the single most important reason why I use the [**SpaceFM**](https://ignorantguru.github.io/spacefm/) file manager on all my machines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### (Very) limited command line options of nautilus

Unfortunately, nautilus does not offer command line options to read the opened directory of its windows, nor does it have any option to *send* an existing window to another directory. Since you cannot remember what you do not see, we are running out of options at first sight.

*However*

We do have `xdotool`, not to do what `nautilus` doesn't, but to at least *fake* the behaviour that you describe. We can do that in such a way that "you would believe it" if you didn't know how it is done.

Although the solution below does not survive a restart, "remembering" (possibly tabbed) window and all opened directories is very well possible within one session. Since you mentioned to be interested in that as a "second choice", here it is.

#### How it works; the process

Although We cannot *close* a window and preserve its tabs and opened directories, we *can* make an existing window seemingly (and completely) disappear, with the help of `xdotool`.

If we subsequently change the behaviour of the `nautilus` launcher in such a way that it *first* looks for possible *unmapped windows* to remap, before opening a new one, effectively we have *exactly* the same behaviour as if `nautilus` would remember the last used window(s).

#### How to set up

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `remember.py`

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os

   app = "nautilus"

   wfile = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.unmapped_"+app

   def get(cmd):
       # simply a helper function
       return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

   def check_windowtype(w_id):
       # check the type of window; only unmap "NORMAL" windows
       return "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL" in get(["xprop", "-id", w_id])

   def get_pid(app):
       # (try to) get the pid of the application 
       try:
           return get(["pgrep", app])
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           pass

   def get_matches(pid):
       # get the window list, select the valid (real) app's windows
       ws = get(["wmctrl", "-lpG"]).splitlines()
       matches = [w.split() for w in ws if pid in w]
       return [w for w in matches if check_windowtype(w[0]) == True]

   try:
       # try to read the file with unmapped windows
       wininf = [l.split() for l in open(wfile).readlines()]
   except FileNotFoundError:
       # if there are no, unmap the current app's windows
       filebrowserwins = get_matches(get_pid(app))
       if filebrowserwins:
           open(wfile, "wt").write(("\n").join((" ").join(l) for l in filebrowserwins))
           for w in [w[0] for w in filebrowserwins]:
               subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "windowunmap", w])
       else:
           arg = "--new-window" if app == "nautilus" else "" 
           subprocess.Popen([app, arg])
   else:
       # re- map unmapped windows
       for w in wininf:
           wid = w[0]; geo = w[3:7]
           subprocess.call(["xdotool", "windowmap", wid])
           subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-ir", wid, "-e", "0,"+(",").join(geo)])
       os.remove(wfile)
   ```
2. The script needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
   ```
3. Copy the `nautilus` launcher from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications`

   for 15.04 and later:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
   ```

   for earlier Ubuntu versions:

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications
   ```
4. open the local copy with gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
   ```

   (in case of `15.04 +`)

   and look for the *first* line, starting with `Exec=`. Change it into:

   ```
   Exec=python3 /path/to/remember.py
   ```

   Save and close the file.
5. Create a keyboard shortcut with the same command: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/remember.py
   ```
6. Now log out and back in

#### How to use

The use is very simple:

- To open a window, do as usual: click on the nautilus launcher. Tab the window as you like:

  [image]
- To close a window *definitively*, close it by clicking on the window's "close" (**x**) box.
- To *preserve* the window(s) + all its tabs:
  press the shortcut key. The window(s) will vanish (seemingly close).

  [image]
- Next time when you click the launcher, the nautilus window(s) will appear exactly like the last time, even the window position(s) will be preserved.

  [image]

***That's it***

#### Note

- In the tests I ran, I couldn't find *any* downside (14.04). If you
  might run into any, please mention!
- In the *How to use* -section, I suggested to click on the nautilus icon to remap possible unmapped windows. The shortcut key will do the same however, so you can see what works the most convenient for you. Also, if you opened a folder by double click *after* you unmapped on or more folders, unmapped folders still will be remapped by the shortcut.

---

### EDIT:

#### Nemo users

Nemo users can equally use the solution above, but:

- In the head section of the script, change:

  ```
  app = "nautilus"
  ```

  into:

  ```
  app = "nemo"
  ```
- In point 3, use:

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
  ```
- In point 4, use:

  ```
  gedit ~/.local/share/applications/nemo.desktop
  ```

*Tested, proved to be working with nemo*

Comment: Great working solution and well documented. Thank you very much!

Comment: @orschiro always fun if it works :) You're welcome!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend using **other file manager** instead if that's okay with you since **Nautilus doesn't have that feature**.

Here's one alternative app that does the trick: [**SpaceFM**](https://github.com/IgnorantGuru/spacefm/wiki)

[Here's how to install it.](https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-16-04-LTS-Xenial-Xerus/how-to-install-spacefm.html)

It has rich features such as, of course, ***reopen last tabs***.

To make it the **default** file manager:

`xdg-mime default spacefm.desktop inode/directory`

Comment: Thank you for mentioning spaceFM. I have been looking for file browser like these.

Answer (score 2):

Try out these scripts to save and restore tabs of nautilus file manager.
https://github.com/susurri/nautilus_save_tabs/

Comment: May be an issue with Wayland: https://github.com/susurri/nautilus_save_tabs/issues/2
I do not see any effect currently.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access folders is bookmarking. You wont keep your tabs open but you can at least see the folders you want quickly (and if you think about it, the bookmarks act as tabs).

Just open a folder on Nautilus, go to Bookmark menu and add a bookmark.