# Restore previously open windows in Nemo at startup on Cinnamon

Tags: 16.04, filemanager, cinnamon, nemo

Is there a way to have Ubuntu automatically open the windows (in the file manager) which were open when it was shut down?

I am using the Cinnamon desktop environment with Nemo as file manager.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/738509/how-can-i-make-nautilus-file-manager-remember-my-open-tabs

Comment: @Zanna Yes, that is why I modified my question, hoping it will be re-opened.

Comment: @Zanna Thanks, and thanks for the edit. I'll be more detailed in the future.

Comment: Hi John, in principal, it does not make a difference if the filebrowser is different. Just need to edit a few characters. Not sure if it will be today, but I will edit the dupe answer and get back to you. Also @Zanna

Comment: Hi John, What is your file browser?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Nemo 2.8.6