# How to write python script which opens last working directory in nautilus (when we launch nautilus)?

Tags: nautilus-elementary, nautilus-script

Elementary OS's file manager opens the last working directory whenever we launch that file manager.

How can I write a script for Nautilus which will work same as given example above?

Comment: why python ? can be bash ?

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus does not keep trace of the last opened folder
But, it keeps trace of recent open files. *See Recent section in Nautilus*

The following 'Ask' gives a good answer : close Nautilus while saving Tabs state
A bit tricky but works:
[How can I make Nautilus file manager remember my open tabs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738509/how-can-i-make-nautilus-file-manager-remember-my-open-tabs)

This script opens Nautilus on the folder of the last opened file
This can be called by a custom launcher `nautilus-last-file.desktop`

```
#!/bin/bash
LastFolder=$(grep -m1 'bookmark href' '~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel' | cut -f2 -d"\"" | cut -c 8-)
LastFolder=$(printf '%b' "${LastFolder//%/\\x}")
LastFolder=$(dirname "$LastFolder")
/usr/bin/nautilus "$LastFolder"
```

Comment: Why do `$(which nautilus) "$LastFolder"` instead of simply `nautilus "$LastFolder"`? Also,   since `recently-used.xbel` is XML, you can use XML tools to accurately parse it: `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//bookmark' -i '(position()=1)' -v '@href' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` (albeit needing additional installation)

Comment: @muru: removed the which... i did select grep because its very fast in handling large text files and because i wanted a out-of-box feature. Of course xmlstarlet do elegant work on xml files but it have to be installed.